# Parsing POST Requests from Multiple Clients in JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing, server

I'm currently using Node.JS to parse POST requests sent to a static endpoint, and store the JSON data in a database. The issue I am having is that all clients might not have the same fields/attributes within their forms, which causes issues when trying to parse. My question is, is there some sort of way to standardize my parsing procedure to general fields (say for instance, I'm parsing a sign up field for multiple websites, each field should have email, password, etc..), or must I create a separate parsing procedure for each client connecting to the endpoint according to the fields their forms provide.

An example of creating a JSON object using the parsed data from a POST request (body):

```
JSON.stringify({
      anonymous_id: body.anonymousId,
      url: body.url,
      email: body.email,
      password: body.password,
      timestamp: (new Date()).toISOString()
    })
```

Comment: Please provide what you are receiving from clients and in what format you want to convert it.

Comment: For this example I am receiving the fields in my code block above, but I also want to assume that the request/body might be exactly formatted as password: xxxx, email: xxxxx

Comment: how about checking for key fields and then saving the whole body object ?

Comment: So checking for the required key fields and if they’re there you can can consider the body “valid”, that might work actually